# Simple Dependency Injection for testing

Tags: c#, ninject, mstest

I'm new at Ninject and I have a very simple requirement, but I couldn't find exaclty what I want in the Ninject's documentation.

I have a class like this:

```
public class User 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    ...
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses {get; protected set;}
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

So, my test class setup needs to instantiate an user for use in many tests.

```
[TestClass]
public class UserTest
{
    User _myUser;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _myUser = new User();
        _myUser.Addresses.Add(new Address { Street = "Evergreen" }); // <-- Here I need Addresses must be Instantiated as, lets say, List<T>
    }
}
```

What I need is that `_myUser.Addresses` will be injected with an instance of a Collection.
I can't figure out on how to accomplish this using Ninject. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: `User` and `Address` are entities. In general you should only use your DI container for managing services.

Comment: So, there is no good reason for use a dependency injector for create my `ICollection<T>` with a concrete implementation by default? If so, I can do something like `_myUser = new User { Addresses = new List<Address>()}` and forget about it, and make the setter public

Comment: You have to remember where DI and DI containers are for: they help making your code more flexible, testable and maintainable by allowing you to hide logic behind abstractions that you might want to change, replace during the lifetime of a project or logic you want to fake/mock during (unit) testing. It is unlikely that this `ICollection<T>` contains any logic that you want to fake during a unit test or replace with other logic later on. You shouldn't try to remove all your `new` statements from your code. Differentiate between [Newables and Injectables](http://bit.ly/12MiAuV).

Comment: Thanks, I will restore the collection creation in my Constructors so. Thank you for the resource link, it just what I was looking for to clarify this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't need Ninject for this. You can do something like this in your model.

```
private ICollection<Address> _addresses;
public ICollection<Address> Addresses
{
    get { return _addresses ?? (_addresses = new HashSet<Address>()); }
    protected set { _addresses = value; }
}
```

This is what I do in my models when I would rather have an empty collection by default instead of a null value.

Comment: I understand what you propose, but I want a model where the responsibility for create the collection instances doesn't belongs to the class. This is because in production, the responsibility for create this collections relies on NHibernate

Comment: I see, I haven't worked with NHibernate before. I use entity framework mostly with my models and it has never had an issue with this design.

Comment: Isn't an issue in NHibernate neither. But, I was thinking that the collection initialization will be superfluous because NHibernate (or EF) will care about it in production. Thanks for you answer

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called 'Property Setter Injection' and [Ninject has a help page in its wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns) with examples.

Comment: Do I really need to add Attributes to my model? It can't be achieved using a more non-intrusive way?